# Evitar hotlinking a carpetas web desde .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Quiero evitar el hotlinking a imágenes de mi web, pero en este caso seria para dos carpetas. En este momento lo tengo configurado para todas las imágenes de esta manera:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?web.es [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://www.web.es/clases-ingles-online/image/sinfoto.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

¿Cómo podría impedir el hotlinkg solamente a dos carpetas de la web y no a todas?

Funcionando ok. He dejado el código así:

```css
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule ^imagen-pre/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://www.web.es/clases-ingles-online/image/sinfoto.jpg [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^imagen-on/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://www.web.es/clases-ingles-online/image/sinfoto.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

Las imagenes de la carpeta imagen-pre se ven en la página sin embargo las de imagen-on no se ven, alguna idea?
Tengo el siguiente código

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?web.es [NC]
RewriteRule ^imagen-pre/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://www.web.es/clases-ingles-online/image/sinfoto.jpg [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^imagen-on/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://www.web.es/clases-ingles-online/image/sinfoto.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Puedes poner otra línea de RewriteRule especificando la carpeta: RewriteRule ^carpeta1/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://www.web.es/carpeta1/imagen-no-permitida.jpg [NC,R,L]

Comment: Funcionando perfectamente. He inlcuido dos lineas una por cada carpeta. Gracias y un saludo